# Event before changing a rich text box

Tags: c#, events

EDIT 1: Sorry, I meant a "text change" in the textbox.
EDIT 2: This is a Windows form application.

I am quite new in programming. Recently, I have been aware of the existence of so-called "Events" which help you implement some additional codes AFTER this particular event happens, e.g. "Text Change in a TextBox". I was wondering if it is possible to trigger the same event, but in this case BEFORE that particular text box changes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What do you mean by "change?"  Size change?  Text change?  Color change?  Etc.

Comment: Is this for a web application, a WinForms application, or something else?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give more details about when you would like the event to trigger?  I wrote an answer under the assumption that "text box changes" means entering text into the TextBox.

Comment: Some events actually have a Before- and AfterEvent version; example TreeView.NodeExpand. Textchanges do not. You could try to work with keydown and do some amount of coding..

Comment: Greetings @TaW. My initial goal was to append some text from speech recognition app to the rich text box, regardless of the position of selection in the rich text box. That is why I was looking for an event before a text change happens.

Comment: You will ahve to check the speech recognition app's interface. But what so you want to do before the change?

Comment: My initial idea was to store the position of selection in a member variable, then moving the selection to the end, then after the event happens, restoring the selection back to its original place.